# Pixel Velocity to vehiclel velocity with stereo camera

Tags: opencv, image-processing, stereo-3d, opticalflow

If we have a stereo camera on a moving vehicle, the optical flow vectors can be used to get the velocity in pixel metrics, how can we convert this pixel velocity to actual vehicle velocity using depth information ?

P.S.Assuming that that all flow vectors are parallel to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Using the stereo you can convert a pixel from the image to a location in space in respective to the car camera. (Treating the car as the 0,0,0 of the world coordinate system). 
In order to determine the velocity of the car do the above process to points that are stationary in respect to the car ( or that you know there relative velocity with respect to the car) for consecutive frames. 
The velocity by definition is the change in location with respect to time so the change of a stationary point in consecutive frames will give you the car velocity.